# Unable to place order with authorized.net direct post magento 2.1.3

Tags: payment, magento-2.1.3, authorize.net, place-order, direct-post

I am having issue with place order with magento 2.1.3 version. When i place order with authorized.net direct post have facing error Which from transact.dll response:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script>
                window.location="http://test.com/authorizenet/directpost_payment/redirect/x_invoice_num/000000142/success/0/error_msg/The transaction was declined because the response hash validation failed./controller_action_name/directpost_payment/";
            </script>
</head>
<body></body>
</html>
```

Also you can see directpost_payment response.

```
<html>
<head>
    <script>
                var require = window.top.require;
        require(
            [
                'jquery',
                'Magento_Ui/js/model/messageList',
                'mage/translate'
            ],
            function($, globalMessageList, $t) {
                var parent = window.top;
                $(parent).trigger('clearTimeout');
                globalMessageList.addErrorMessage({
                    message: $t('An error occurred on the server. Please try to place the order again.')
                });
            }
        );
            </script>
</head>
<body></body>
</html>
```

But when i check in admin order was placed successfully. But getting this error.
can you please help me resolve the issue.

---

Now you can see transaction log which got from place order with authorized.net payment process

you can see transaction log

```
[2017-02-13 09:50:58] main.DEBUG: cache_invalidate:  {"method":"POST","url":"http://test.com/authorizenet/directpost_payment/place/","invalidateInfo":{"tags":["catalog_product_186","FPC"],"mode":"matchingTag"},"is_exception":false} []
[2017-02-13 09:50:58] main.DEBUG: array (
'request' => 
array (
'x_version' => '3.1',
'x_delim_data' => 'FALSE',
'x_relay_response' => 'TRUE',
'x_test_request' => 'TRUE',
'x_login' => '****',
'x_method' => 'CC',
'x_relay_url' => 'http://test.com/authorizenet/directpost_payment/response',
'x_type' => 'AUTH_ONLY',
'x_fp_sequence' => '46',
'x_invoice_num' => '000000043',
'x_amount' => 1070,
'x_currency_code' => 'USD',
'x_tax' => '0.00',
'x_freight' => '50.00',
'x_first_name' => 'ueyri',
'x_last_name' => 'ueryd',
'x_company' => 'yehdomfo',
'x_address' => '12 afriars Rd. suite #101',
'x_city' => 'san diego',
'x_state' => 'California',
'x_zip' => '92108',
'x_country' => '',
'x_phone' => '7894567894',
'x_fax' => '',
'x_cust_id' => '',
'x_customer_ip' => '27.109.11.50',
'x_customer_tax_id' => '',
'x_email' => 'perso@gmail.com',
'x_email_customer' => '0',
'x_merchant_email' => '',
'x_ship_to_first_name' => 'ueyri',
'x_ship_to_last_name' => 'ueryd',
'x_ship_to_company' => 'yehdomfo',
'x_ship_to_address' => '12 afriars Rd. suite #101',
'x_ship_to_city' => 'san diego',
'x_ship_to_state' => 'California',
'x_ship_to_zip' => '92108',
'x_ship_to_country' => '',
'x_po_num' => '',
'x_fp_timestamp' => 1486979458,
'x_fp_hash' => 'ce0e2ffa92cea2431317d2bab59d3f56',
),
) {"is_exception":false} []
[2017-02-13 09:51:00] main.DEBUG: array (
'response' => 
array (
'x_response_code' => '1',
'x_response_reason_code' => '1',
'x_response_reason_text' => '(TESTMODE) This transaction has been approved.',
'x_avs_code' => 'P',
'x_auth_code' => '000000',
'x_trans_id' => '0',
'x_method' => 'CC',
'x_card_type' => 'Visa',
'x_account_number' => 'XXXX1111',
'x_first_name' => 'ueyri',
'x_last_name' => 'ueryd',
'x_company' => 'yehdomfo',
'x_address' => '12 afriars Rd. suite #101',
'x_city' => 'san diego',
'x_state' => 'California',
'x_zip' => '92108',
'x_country' => '',
'x_phone' => '7894567894',
'x_fax' => '',
'x_email' => 'perso@gmail.com',
'x_invoice_num' => '000000043',
'x_description' => '',
'x_type' => 'auth_only',
'x_cust_id' => '',
'x_ship_to_first_name' => 'ueyri',
'x_ship_to_last_name' => 'ueryd',
'x_ship_to_company' => 'yehdomfo',
'x_ship_to_address' => '12 afriars Rd. suite #101',
'x_ship_to_city' => 'san diego',
'x_ship_to_state' => 'California',
'x_ship_to_zip' => '92108',
'x_ship_to_country' => '',
'x_amount' => '1070.00',
'x_tax' => '0.00',
'x_duty' => '0.00',
'x_freight' => '50.00',
'x_tax_exempt' => 'FALSE',
'x_po_num' => '',
'x_MD5_Hash' => '6CA68F12F818D6441D0F44E74E0C906F',
'x_SHA2_Hash' => 'A7085921046F765BF6A39DCEAACBE1356D84DDD18B2A31F5FB9E764AB3B89233F95275922C536E87DBBB9DA515821F01AD6517FB45B8ED370EE0DFE617EE9B6F',
'x_cvv2_resp_code' => '',
'x_cavv_response' => '',
'x_test_request' => 'true',
'controller_action_name' => 'directpost_payment',
'is_secure' => '',
),
 ) {"is_exception":false} []
```

so please help to how to resolve this issue.

Comment: You can look into Magento debug.log to find a response from Authorize.net payment gateway.

Comment: Hello,

I have check in log file and i got something. you can see below error.

main.DEBUG: cache_invalidate:  {"method":"POST","url":"http://test.com/authorizenet/directpost_payment/place/","invalidateInfo":{"tags":["catalog_product_186","FPC"],"mode":"matchingTag"},"is_exception":false} []

can you help to solve the issue.

Comment: You need to enable debug option for Authorize.net payment and provide transaction log details.

Comment: I apply same this but facing same issue can you please help me solve this error

Comment: Can you provide transaction details from debug log? Without them, unfortunately, I can't help you.

Comment: please find below answer